# Accessing JSON objects details

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple form that submits details of an address of a selected location. Before submitting I would like to allow user to preview the address that is going to be sent. The addresses are stored in JSON object. I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<html>
<form action="something.asp" >
<select id="selectAddress">
   <option value="Cheonan2">Cheonan 2</option>
   <option value="Cheonan3">Cheonan 3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Display addresses" onClick="showAddress()"/><br>

<span id="addressField1"></span>
<span id="addressField2"></span>
<span id="addressField3"></span>
</html>
```

JS:

```
<script>
function showAddress()
{
    var JSONAddress =
        [
            {           "id":"Cheonan2",
                        "Field1": "96, 3Gongdan1-ro",
                        "Field2": "Seobuk-gu, Cheonan-si",
                        "Field3": "Chungcheongnam-do, 31093, Korea"
            },

            {
                        "id":"Cheonan3",
                        "Field1": "80, 3Gongdan6-ro,",
                        "Field2": "Seobuk-gu, Cheonan-si,",
                        "Field3": "Chungcheongnam-do, 31085, Korea"
            }

        ];


    var e=document.getElementById("selectAddress");
    var selectedAddress = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    for (var i;i<JSONAddress.length;i++){
        if (JSONAddress[i].id===selectedAddress){
                                    document.getElementById('addressField1').innerHTML=JSONAddress[i].Field1;
                document.getElementById('addressField2').innerHTML=JSONAddress[i].Field2;
                document.getElementById('addressField3').innerHTML=JSONAddress[i].Field3;

            }

        }

}
</script>
```

I am probably accessing the objects in the `JSONAddress` wrong because the function doesn't show anything...can you help?

Comment: can you provide the code on fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with variable `i` of `for` loop which was not **initialize** to **0**.

```js
function showAddress()
{
    var JSONAddress =
        [
            {           "id":"Cheonan2",
                        "Field1": "96, 3Gongdan1-ro",
                        "Field2": "Seobuk-gu, Cheonan-si",
                        "Field3": "Chungcheongnam-do, 31093, Korea"
            },

            {
                        "id":"Cheonan3",
                        "Field1": "80, 3Gongdan6-ro,",
                        "Field2": "Seobuk-gu, Cheonan-si,",
                        "Field3": "Chungcheongnam-do, 31085, Korea"
            }

        ];


    var e=document.getElementById("selectAddress");
    var selectedAddress = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    for (var i=0;i<JSONAddress.length;i++){
        if (JSONAddress[i].id===selectedAddress){
                                    document.getElementById('addressField1').innerHTML=JSONAddress[i].Field1;
                document.getElementById('addressField2').innerHTML=JSONAddress[i].Field2;
                document.getElementById('addressField3').innerHTML=JSONAddress[i].Field3;

            }

        }

}
```

```html
<html>
<form action="something.asp" >
<select id="selectAddress">
   <option value="Cheonan2">Cheonan 2</option>
   <option value="Cheonan3">Cheonan 3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<input type="button" value="Display addresses" onClick="showAddress()"/><br>

<span id="addressField1"></span>
<span id="addressField2"></span>
<span id="addressField3"></span>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you didn't initialize the `var i` to `0` in your loop.

Second, (in your fiddle) you used `getElementById` - It should have been `document.getElementById`

Third, (in your fiddle) there is `json.JSONAddress` - It should be only `JSONAddress`

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/am25kaxk/20/).

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always initialize `variable` otherwise the value will be `undefined` and use `document.getElementById` instead of `getElementById`.